# Display equally spaced x-axis labels MATLAB from array

Tags: matlab, axes

I am trying to display an image using `imagesc` as below with the x-axis from 1D array `xax` but I get my x-axis with bunched up numbers.
I would like to have the x-axis be equally spaced.
Any tips would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
colormap gray;
xax = zeros;
raw5mm = zeros;

% Read inputs (r5mm Cylinder scatterer)
data5mm = readmatrix('Port_3_U_freq_Absolute_cyl_r5_d20.dat');

% Convert to spatial-z domain
for i=1:length(data5mm)
    raw5mm(1,i) = data5mm(i,2);
end

for j=0:132:(length(data5mm)-1)
    disp(j);
    k = j+1;
    xax(1,k) = (-0.4853*((data5mm(k,1)/(10^9))^2))+(43.764*(data5mm(k,1)/(10^9)))-673.85;
end
xax = nonzeros(xax);
xax = transpose(xax);

% Plotting image
imagesc(raw5mm);
set(gca,'XTick',[1:length(xax)],'XTickLabel',xax);
clear;
```

**Output:**
[image: Output]

Comment: well, you are setting a bunch of numbers. Note that every pixel is a potential tick, so if you set the first ticks by `[1:length(xax)]`, they will be plotted there... overlaying each other. Use something like `[1:size(raw5mm,2)/length(xax):size(raw5mm,2)]` to have them equally spaced along the whole x-axis

Comment: @max thanks for the tip. I'm a complete novice when it comes to MATLAB so I'm still figuring my way around.